# javascript: don't return until a promise resolves

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I need to wait until a promise resolves before I return from my function. Basically, I need to perform something synchronously, and JavaScript doesn't seem to like that idea.

Here's a simple example. I have a function that returns a promise, but the promise can't be created until after another promise resolves.  The result is my code looks like this:

```
const lib = require('lib')

var ret_promise
lib.func1().then(() => {
  ret_promise = lib.func2()
})

return ret_promise
```

The problem is that the outer promise is created, then it immediately moves on to the return, and returns `undefined` because the `then` hasn't executed yet. I can't put the `return` inside the `then`, because all that will happen is it will return from the interior arrow function.

How do I do this?  Is it even possible?

NOTE: I'm using node 6. I can't use `async/await`

Comment: It isn't possible. You'll want to return the promise instead.

Comment: it actually makes things quite easy, `return lib.func1().then(() => lib.func2());` then you just attach a `.then` to it later to get the result.

Comment: @KevinB I don't follow. That returns the outer promise, which is of no use to me.

Comment: If it were possible for functions to arbitrarily pause the event loop, that would pause the entire node app meaning all requests would be pending until said function completed. There are a few apis available that do that, such as fs.readSync, but they still suffer from the same problem caused by pausing the event loop.

Comment: Why doesn't the outer promise work? promises in javascript can be chained

Comment: Async/await doesn't get you out of this problem either, since at the end you've still got a promise to wait on just as you do now.

Comment: what I ultimately need is to get the inner promise back when I call the function. For example, I'm writing a unit test and I need to verify that the inner promise resolves with a certain result.  If I return the outer promise, the inner promise is out of scope (I think)

Comment: thats... what my code in the comment does. It returns a promise that will resolve when lib.func2() resolves. the .then alters the promise before it is returned such that it will first wait for func1, then func2, before it resolves.

Comment: i'm not sure how to answer that other than... that's how it works

Comment: It looks like what's happening there is that the outer promise is created and resolves, then after the outer promise resolves, the inner promise is created.  the arrow function returns the inner promise, but by the time you get there, the outer promise's `resolve()` has already been called. Otherwise you wouldn't have reached the `then` yet.

Comment: It's totally possible that I just have absolutely no idea how promises work. thanks for bearing with me here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158348/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-ewok).

Comment: *"I can't put the return inside the then"* : yes you can: that return value is used as promised value for the promise returned by `func1().then()`. But don't expect asynchronous results to become available synchronously. It is a change of thinking: you can do all you want while keeping with the asynchronous pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, all you really need to change is return the original promise, and then within it's .then return the second one. The promise returned from the function will then resolve once the second promise resolves.

```
const lib = require('lib')

var ret_promise = lib.func1().then(() => {
  return lib.func2()
})

return ret_promise
```

which can be simplified to

```
const lib = require('lib');

return lib.func1().then(() => lib.func2());
```